# How to make subfloat figures wider vertically

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to make the subfloat figures wider but I couldn't, It looks very small and narrow as shown below .. any ideas??
[image]

My Code:

```
\begin{figure*}
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.35\linewidth]{score3/1.png}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.35\linewidth]{score3/2.png}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.35\linewidth]{score3/3.png}}
 \caption{trial}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: the line is already wider than the specified text width by 5% plus the width of two spaces. Why do you say it is _narrow_ ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I mean vertically not horizontally.

Comment: well assuming the aspect ratio of your figures is fixed, you can't make them taller unless you have less on a line. They would look better if they were all the same size, but that's a matter for your plotting software. Also do you have to use png? a vector format would be much better for a line graph

Comment: Is there a way we change the height of each image so we can make it taller ?

Comment: If you ask it to, latex will distort the images yes, just put height=5cm into the option but don't do that!

Comment: incidentally the images will not be centred as your line is overfull (you must get a warning) they will stick into the right margin.